# what is the best way to mock variables in __init__ method python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following class, which uses a function to load config values from a file. `load_config` essentially converts the property in question in the yaml into a string.

```
import load_config
import sys

class Example:
   def __init__(self):
       parser = ArgumentParser()
       self.args  = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])
       self.conf  = self.args + {"val_b": "green"}
       self.val_a = load_config(self.conf, "val_a")
       self.val_b = load_config(self.conf, "val_b")
       
       if not self.val_a:
          raise ValeError()
       if not self.val_b:
          raise ValeError()
```

self.args loads arguments from the CLI. Imagine, for this example, self.conf is a merge of CLI args and hard coded args into a python dict.

I'm trying to test against the **if** conditions. How can I patch or pass fake values to `self.val_a` and `self.val_b` so that I can raise the exceptions and have a test case against it?

Since val_a comes from CLI, I can patch sys.argv as `patch("sys.argv", self.cli_arguments)`, but how can I patch or is it possible to pass a fake value to self.val_b during instantiation?

I don't want to patch the call to `load_config` because I want to run separate tests that confirm the if statements get triggered.

Comment: Since `val_a` and `val_b` are loaded from `sys.argv`, you just need to provide an appropriate value for `sys.argv`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Aran-Fey val_b is coming from a config file. In the example above I just set it as a dict so it was easier to understand, but val_a does come from sys.argv